# Sprites blink randomly on Android

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have created a platformer-runner game using cocos2d-x 3.1. In that game the screen scrolls infinitely and some obstacles appear in front on the player, and the player can jump up in order to avoid obstacles.

I have developed the game on Windows and didn't use `SpriteBatchNode` - just simple `Sprites` and particle effects. On windows it was OK, but when I ported **on Android some of the sprites (big and small, moving and in rest) started to blink randomly**. First I thought it is the Z order that is being changed randomly, but I have removed the most part of sprites out of the screen and saw that they just blink. Interestingly I could not find any common property between blinking sprites, but those which blink always blink, and those that don't blink (normal behavior), they are OK always.

I could get rid of this nasty situation by using `SpriteBatchNode` for all the sprites that were blinking. But could not understand what is going on, what was the reason. Are there any assumptions what could be the reason for this kind of behavior?

I still need to use some simple `Sprite`s in order to be able to add particle effects as child to them. It is not possible to do with `SpriteBatchNodes`and with `Sprite`s that are created by using `SpriteBatchNodes` like this: `Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("my.png")`.

Sorry that I don't share some code. I just don't know what to share - the project is huge. But if you need some concrete parts, I could share, of course.

Comment: Have you tried other Android hardware? `SpriteBatchNode` would really help. The Cocos2d-x forums have had some recent discussion about `SpriteBatchNode` and Android

Comment: @GameDeveloper "I could get rid of this nasty situation by using SpriteBatchNode...", so yes I have tried :). I hoped for a link "some recent discussion about SpriteBatchNode and Android".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GameDeveloper I finally could reproduce the problem of randomly blinking. As I understand it is the problem of Z order. I have reproduced it in the following way. I create an empty sprite, and into that sprite I create and addChild the same image. On tap of the screen I add one more sprite in the same position it was the tap. After the 16-th tap each tap changes some of the Z orders of already added sprites. The thing is that each sprite I add, I don't specify higher Z order. But I cannot understand what kind of magic number is the 16. BTW I have also implemented undo functionality, where I remove last added sprite. If I undo to have not more than 16 sprites, it is OK. Once I exceed 16 again, the Z order randomization begins.